# Why isn't the comparison of charAt and String.valueOf returning true when they're the same value?

Tags: java, cookies

Here's my program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lottery
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //declare and initialized variables and objects
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String lotteryNum = "";
    String userGuess = "";

    //Generate a 3-digit "lottery" number composed of random numbers
    int num1 = (int)(Math.random()*10);
    int num2 = (int)(Math.random()*10);
    int num3 = (int)(Math.random()*10);
    //Simulate a lottery by drawing one number at a time and 
    //concatenating it to the string
    String c1 = String.valueOf(num1);
    String c2 = String.valueOf(num2);
    String c3 = String.valueOf(num3);
    lotteryNum = (c1+c2+c3);
    //Identify the repeated steps and use a for loop structure
    //Input: Ask user to guess 3 digit number
    System.out.println("WINNER:"+lotteryNum+" Please enter your three numbers (e.g. 123): ");
    userGuess = input.next();
    System.out.println(c1.equals(userGuess.charAt(0)));
    System.out.println(userGuess.charAt(0) +"   " + userGuess.charAt(1) + "     " + userGuess.charAt(2) + "\n" + c1 + "\t"+c2+"\t"+c3);;
    if (c1.equals(userGuess.charAt(0)) && c2.equals(userGuess.charAt(1)))
        System.out.println("Winner: "+ lotteryNum+"\nCongratulations, the front pair matched.");
    else if (c2.equals(userGuess.charAt(1)) && c3.equals(userGuess.charAt(2)))
        System.out.println("Winner: "+ lotteryNum+"\nCongratulations, the end pair matched.");
    else if (c1.equals(userGuess.charAt(0)) && c2.equals(userGuess.charAt(1)) && c3.equals(userGuess.charAt(2)))
        System.out.println("Winner: "+ lotteryNum+"\nCongratulations, both pairs matched.");
    else 
                System.out.println("Winner: "+ lotteryNum+"\nSorry, no matches. You only had \n one chance out of 100 to win anyay.");

} //end main
}//end class Lottery
```

For some reason, the lines with logic such as:

```
System.out.println(c1.equals(userGuess.charAt(0)));
```

Specifically return `false`, even if the user enters the same value, i.e. `String.valueOf(num1)` is the same value as `userGuess.charAt(0)`, and I even considered both of them as strings, but it still returns false. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userGuess.charAt(0)` returns `char`
whereas

```
c1 is String
```

can use `String.valueOf` as suggested.

You can also use ,`Character.toString(char);`

```
System.out.println(c1.equals(Character.toString(userGuess.charAt(0))));
```

We need to convert either `String to char` or `char to String` and then compare

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Because a `String` is not a `char`.

```
if (c1.equals(String.valueOf(userGuess.charAt(0))) 
        && c2.equals(String.valueOf(userGuess.charAt(1))))
```

**or** the shorter

```
if (c1.charAt(0) == userGuess.charAt(0) && c2.charAt(0) == userGuess.charAt(1))
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized this slowly after I posted the question! Thanks a lot!